# How to disable an IMAP capability in Dovecot?

Tags: dovecot, imap

For testing purposes, I want to disable specific capabilities in a Dovecot IMAP Server. In the documentation, I only find

> ```
> imap_capability
> Default: <empty>
> Values: String
> ```
>
> Override the IMAP CAPABILITY response.
>
> If the value begins with the + character, the capabilities listed here are added at the end of the default string.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> imap_capability = +XFOO XBAR
> ```

However, it does not explain how to *disable* a single capability?

Comment: Without looking at the documentation I would expect `-` to disable a capability. Or omit the `+` to replace the current capabilities with the given string.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Unfortunately the `-` does not work, resulting in `CAPABILITY -CONDSTORE AUTH=PLAIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the explanation in this post](https://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2010-January/046100.html):

> Set imap_capability string explicitly and [the mail client] won't use it. The
> string shouldn't contain AUTH=* or STARTTLS. Easiest if you just:
>
> ```
> telnet localhost 143
> a login user pass
> b capability
> ```
>
> Then from that capability just remove CONDSTORE and put it to
> imap_capability.

Following these instructions in the attempt to remove `CONDSTORE` capability:

```
imap_capability =  IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SNIPPET=FUZZY PREVIEW=FUZZY PREVIEW STATUS=SIZE SAVEDATE LITERAL+ NOTIFY
```

Note that `IMAP4rev1` must be explicitly included in `imap_capabilities`.

This seems to work, but I noticed that the initial capabilities string (the one presented upon initial connection, but before login) changes, which I would not expect, from originally

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
```

to

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SNIPPET=FUZZY PREVIEW=FUZZY PREVIEW STATUS=SIZE SAVEDATE LITERAL+ NOTIFY AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
```

I'm not sure if this can cause any issues.